# cython when to use 'compile time' types

Tags: python, types, cython

When writing cython code to be used from python, when should I use a 'compile time' type (e.g. `np.float64_t`) versus a regular type (e.g. `np.float64`)?

For example, in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481465/230468), it is suggested that one function be given the compile time version, and the other not.  Why is this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433318/difference-of-c-type-and-compile-time-type-in-cython) asks a similar question, but the marked solution doesn't provide any kind of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, in the place where expects compile time type, you cannot use regular type, vise versa.

So you can do this: `cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t] a = np.zeros(100, dtype=np.float64)`. But you cannot swap the 2 types.

You can do this: `np.ndarray[double] a = np.zero(100, dtype=np.double)`, 
but not `np.ndarray[np.double] a = np.zero(100, dtype=double)`.

Comment: What *should* I do though ? what is faster ?